# How to remove the error "SystemError: initialization of _internal failed without raising an exception"

Tags: python, import, nlp, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import Top2Vec package for nlp topic modelling. But even after upgrading pip, numpy this error is coming.

I tried

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

I was expecting to run

```
from top2vec import Top2Vec

model = Top2Vec(FAQs, speed='learn', workers=8)
```

but it is giving the mentioned error

Comment: A [similar issue exists in `python-numba`](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8615).

Answer (score 65):

It's probably related to the latest numpy release (v1.24.0). Try installing version 1.23.5:

```
pip install numpy==1.23.5
```

Comment: I have the same issue but probably for a different reason. Here is the link to my question if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190844/how-to-resolve-systemerror-initialization-of-internal-failed-without-raising-a

Answer (score 23):

For me, `numba` caused the error, which was shown inside the error message. Updating `numba` solved the problem:

```
pip install -U numba
```

Comment: I was source building a package and faced this error, checking `conda list` didnt list numba but importing numba gave that error, just a 'pip install numba' sorted it for me. I am still wondering why it didn't throw the ModuleNotFound error...

Comment: In my case this worked in AzureML environment.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't `from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder`. It now works thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 16):

For me it was not the numpy release as I was already on the version `1.23.5`.
I simply restarted the kernel and re-imported `top2vec` and it worked.

P.S. I was on an AWS Linux machine

Comment: worked for me! Python 3.9, Mac M1 pro

Answer (score 0):

In my case, as for @CGFoX, I needed to uninstall and reinstall `numba`.  The catch was that `numba` had been introduced by installing `umap` but then changed when I later imported `scikit-image`.  After the latter import I had to reinstall `numba-0.56.4` to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error that required updating `numba`. The root issue was that my Python environment was pinned to Python 3.9. Updating the whole environment to Python 3.10 resolved the issue.