# How to resolve SystemError: initialization of _internal failed without raising an exception?

Tags: python-3.x, regression, numba, pycaret, system-error

**Problem**

I have written a code that takes some historical data as input. Assuming dataset has a `timeseries` format, I am trying to do a regression and find a predictor.

**Code**

For my project, I have four files: `my_project.py`, `utilities.py`, `plotter.py`, and `constants.py`. Here is some small portions (relevant imports) of the two scripts:

1. `my_project.py`:

   from time import perf_counter

   from constants import (output_dir, DATAPATH, output_file)

   from utilities import (dataframe_in_nutshell, excel_reader, info_printer, sys, module_creator, process_discovery, data_explanatory_analysis, excel_reader, df_cleaner, feature_extractor, ml_modelling)

   from plotter import Plotter
2. `utilities.py`

   import os

   import sys
   import inspect

   from pathlib import Path

   from typing import (Iterable, List, Tuple, Optional)

   from itertools import zip_longest

   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt

   import statsmodels.api as sm

   import pandas as pd

   from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

   from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

   from pycaret.regression import (setup, compare_models, predict_model, plot_model, finalize_model, load_model)

   import csv

   from constants import (np, Path, nan_value, plots_dir, HOURS_PER_WEEK, LAGS_STEP_NUM, rc_params, NA_VALUES, COLUMNS_NAMES, string_columns, LAGS_LABELS, numeric_columns, output_dir, DATAPATH, dtype_dict, train_size)

   from pprint import PrettyPrinter

   pp = PrettyPrinter()

   import seaborn as sns

   sns.set()

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\project\my_project.py", line 10, in <module>
    from utilities import (dataframe_in_nutshell, excel_reader, info_printer, sys, module_creator,
  File "c:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\project\utilities.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pycaret.regression import (setup, compare_models, predict_model, plot_model, finalize_model,
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\pycaret\regression.py", line 10, in <module>        
    import pycaret.internal.tabular
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\pycaret\internal\tabular.py", line 48, in <module>  
    import pycaret.internal.preprocess
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\pycaret\internal\preprocess.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pyod.models.knn import KNN
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\pyod\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\pyod\utils\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>        
    from .stat_models import pairwise_distances_no_broadcast
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\pyod\utils\stat_models.py", line 11, in <module>    
    from numba import njit
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\numba\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from numba.np.ufunc import (vectorize, guvectorize, threading_layer,
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>    
    from numba.np.ufunc.decorators import Vectorize, GUVectorize, vectorize, guvectorize
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\decorators.py", line 3, in <module>  
    from numba.np.ufunc import _internal
SystemError: initialization of _internal failed without raising an exception
```

**Logistics**

1. I am running my_project.py in visual studio code on a Windows 10 machine.
2. All packages are based on Python 3.10 using conda-forge channel

**Research**

The following pages seem to explain a workaround but I am not sure if I am understanding the issue in here. I would appreciate if you can help me figure this out.

[Error on import with numpy HEAD](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8615)

[Update ufunc loop signature resolution to use NumPy](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8538)

[Remove reliance on npy_ ufunc loops.](https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/8544)

Answer (score 13):

I had this very same issue today.

Solved it by downgrading Numpy to 1.23.1

So: `pip install numpy==1.23.1`

Comment: Based on the issue in numba, use `numpy<=1.24.0` for now. See https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8615#issuecomment-1434358853